# Use jQuery to reference other javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically Im working with Sharepoint, help me god!

Sharepoint does some crazy the things but Im hoping what I want to do can be achieved using jQuery.

Sharepoint is writing some image values into a table:

```
  <script>
    fNewItem = false;
    InsertItem("http://dev_site/sites/Pictures/Waves.jpg",  
    "5", 
    "BlueWaves",
    "jpg", 
    "1920", 
    "1080",
    "/_layouts/images/icjpg.gif", fNewItem);
  </script>
```

There are a number of these output by Sharepoint, this snippet is from a Sharepoint Gallery so I'd need to loop through the page to find all of these so that I can grab all of the images.

What I want to know is if there is anyway for me to grab these values using jQuery and then output them again?

Comment: Would it work to iterate over the images in the table once added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code ([LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/A9FWS/)) ... you may need to tweak the `if()` statement a bit to determine which `<script>..</script>` blocks you want to deal with or not.

```
$('script').each(function(){
    var t = $(this).text();
    if (t.indexOf('fNewItem')>0 && t.indexOf('CDATA')<=0){
       var a = t.split(/[\r\n]+/); //Split on Line Break
        for (var x = 0; x<a.length; x++){
            $('#result').append(a[x] + '<br>');
        } 
        $('#result').append('<hr>');
    }
});
```